# How to make jq output comma separated when key is absent

Tags: json, bash, jq

I am trying to fetch message field from below json file in comma separated value

```
[
   {
      "title":"second bad commit",
      "message":"second bad commit"
   },
   {
      "title":"first bad commit",
      "message":"first bad commit",
   }
]
```

My attempt to do that with jq: `jq -r '.message | join(",")'`

It keeps throwing following error:
`jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index array with string "message"`

So, how can I make jq output comma separated when key is absent

Comment: Your posted JSON is invalid, can you please fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your data is actually:

```
[
   {
      "title":"second bad commit",
      "message":"second bad commit"
   },
   {
      "title":"first bad commit",
      "message":"first bad commit"
   }
]
```

Then you'll need to use `map` to map each value:

```
$ jq 'map(.message)'           
[
  "second bad commit",
  "first bad commit"
]
```

And then just the join pipe:

```
$ jq 'map(.message) | join(",")'
"second bad commit,first bad commit"
```

And then adding `-r` to output the raw value.:

```
$ jq -r 'map(.message) | join(",")'
second bad commit,first bad commit
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas! This is exactly what I was looking for, kudos to you.